# Save and overwrite CustomXMLParts

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I have methods that read and write a serialized object to the CustomXMLPart of a PowerPoint document.
Currently if I make changes to the object and write it back to the XMLPart it creates a new XMLPart. Is there a way to overwrite the existing XMLPart? Or do I have to delete the existing and then add the new one?

Read Method:

```
private void Application_AfterPresentationOpen(PowerPoint.Presentation presentation)
{
    Office.CustomXMLParts settingsXmlParts = presentation.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("Document.Settings");

    if (settingsXmlParts.Count <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using StringReader streamReader = new StringReader(settingsXmlParts[1].XML);

    _ = (Settings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
}
```

Write Method:

```
private void Application_PresentationBeforeSave(PowerPoint.Presentation presentation, ref bool cancel)
{
    if (!ResultsAreLoaded)
    {
        return;
    }

    Settings settings = new Settings();

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, settings);

    _ = presentation.CustomXMLParts.Add(stringWriter.ToString(), missing);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the existing one before adding the new one, don't know of a way to actually overwrite it, that is how I do it.

```
Office.CustomXMLParts settingsXmlParts = presentation.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("Document.Settings");
foreach (var settingsXmlPart in settingsXmlParts)
     settingsXmlPart.Delete();
```

Or

```
Office.CustomXMLPart settingsXmlPart = presentation.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("Document.Settings").FirstOrDefault();
if (settingsXmlPart != null)
     settingsXmlPart.Delete();
```